# Почему считывание двумерного массива такое долгое

Tags: c#

Пытаюсь считать массив целых чисел. Естественно мне на вход попадают строки и... При решении задач, происходит ошибка по времени. Как я убедился это из-за считывания массива

```
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        {
            s = Console.ReadLine().Split(' ').Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
            for (int z = 0; z < N; z++)
                listarr[i, z] = s[z];
        }
```

Собственно, как в C# можно сделать считывание двумерного массива быстрее?

Comment: Сколько времени занимает обработка введённой строки и выполнение вложенного цикла?

Comment: Вероятно, нужно читать не из консоли, а из файла. Или забить данные прямо в код.

Comment: Скорее всего на вход приходит не N строк, а меньше (или вообще одна строка), и ваш код тупо висит на ReadLine

Comment: 1) Число N точно задано
2) Я отправляю задачу на сервер, ввод происходит не из файла
3) Есть ли идеи как можно сделать другим способом?

Comment: В C# "считывание двумерного массива" ничем не отличается от считывания одномерного. Это не проблема производительности. Скорее всего ваш код пытается читать не то количество строк, которое ему дается на вход в консоли. Например, разделитель строки не совпадает с ожидаемым, и все приходит одной строкой. Попробуйте локализовать проблему - читать не N строк, а только первую. Потом N/2. N-1. Наверняка код начнет "тупить" не на большом числе N, а просто на каком-то граничном

Comment: я точно знаю, что подаются N строк, одна за другой. Я не могу считать первую, а потом резко последнюю строку